# How to implement assistiveTouch like feature in android?

Tags: android, shortcut

iOS has a feature called assistive touch in which a small dot is shown forever and clicking it opens a shortcut popup. Similar feature in android is make available by GO Launcher team - Toucher. How can I implement it in my application ?